# Android ListView pre-loading rows of data

Tags: android, listview

I have an Android ListView in my application and I am displaying different images in each row (1 image per row, of undefined height) The images are loaded using AsyncTask from the web, otherwise it pulls it from cache, so that's all fine.

Process is, I have an url to an image, in each getView of my adapter (unless found in cache) I fire an async task to set my ImageView with image. I give it a defined width, to fit in screen (I then use this defined width to scale the height, so I do know the width but don't know the height (or aspect ratio of image) before downloading and setting it)

When scrolling down everything is ok, because List View pre-loads like 5 rows.. it fires off 5 calls to download image in my code. And that makes scrolling down smooth.
The issue is when I am scrolling up. When I scroll up, the view gets reused, I know a width so thats ok, but initially the height is 0, until I fully load image; when it is loaded fully, the Image View gets expanded to whatever height (i.e 1024) and that makes scrolling choppy, since it expands view from 0 to 1024 and brings focus back to top of that view...

QUESTION: Is it possible to set the List View to preload both scrolling down and up to a certain size.. ? So when scrolling up, my ListView has like 5 rows ready to show. I know this is possible with android.support.v4.view.ViewPager (by default it pre-loads +1 and -1..but that can be changed to +5 and -5)

Comment: What are you using as an adapter? Within it, are you using bindView?

Comment: I am using BaseAdapter.. just using getView, inflating one of my layout, setting views to whatever I want and returning it.

Comment: I have sort of a solution.. as I download a new image, I record the height and put it in HashMap, so later, check if its cached image, if it is, I know its height, so set image view objects width and height and it doesn't jump around.. but this could be troublesome with re-creating Fragments/Activities during their lifecycle... Not sure how to pass that around.

Comment: I just came across this [blog post](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/) about `RecyclerView`. (a) this might be of interest for you anyways, and (b) it mentions the `ViewHolder` pattern that deals with a similar use case.

Comment: With listview , you are calling asynctask for each row.. so when you scroll up down randomly then it'll be calling only 1 asynchtask for each row ?

Comment: Yes, each row of my listview contains couple of buttons, imageview and some textviews. when I scroll it sets texts (from arraylist, depending on position) sets image url to imageview (if not cached yet) do async task to fetch it. So yes, 1 per each row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override `newView`, instead of `getView`, in your adapter, which extends `BaseAdapter`, as far as I understand. Don't forget to call `super.newView`.

The reason is to avoid binding views (rows) when you scroll up. Method `newView` is called once and only once for each row. And `getView` also binds views, which makes images load again, as you scroll back up. I think that's the catch, if I remember it correctly.

Of course, this only makes sense if images don't change, once you load 'em. If images are supposed to change dynamically, while scrolling up and down, I guess you're stuck, but I doubt that's the case. You wouldn't save the height of an old/discarded image, I assume.

Comment: Also, you could load height as data, one number from server, within your AsyncTask. It has to be much faster.

Comment: Right, they do not, I pull an array of URLs in a certain order and display them, sometimes, on refresh that order might change, but thats why I am hashing URL to height and not position to height.

Comment: I have looked at newView method.. it doesn't have a position? I am accessing all of my data using that and arraylists.. I haven't used anything but getView, so I might be missing something

Comment: Well, if positions change, I haven't got a clue what to do. Maybe quickly load heights/urls as data/numbers?

Comment: I guess I will adjust my database to hold the width and height, and get that info in the request that I get the rest of the info, and set imageView before attempting to download it. 
Many Thanks.

Comment: @vankizer: You're welcome. I hope someone gives you a better answer. I don't see another way that doesn't involve a lot more work.